# Oracle JET : Want to create a login page in which after click on login button should route me to home page

Tags: oracle, oracle-jet

Hi I am using the example application with navigation list but I want to create a login page on top of it in which once I click login button and after authentication i have to route the application to main page.
I tried below code but nothing happened.
oj.Router.rootInstance.go('login');

please help.

Application : Oracle JET distribution

Code:

function (oj, ko, app) { // this callback gets executed when all required modules are loaded

```
$(function() {

  function init() {
    oj.Router.sync().then(
      function () {
        // Bind your ViewModel for the content of the whole page body.
        ko.applyBindings(app, document.getElementById('globalBody'));
        // navigate the user to login or wherever you want them to be now
        oj.Router.rootInstance.go('login');
      },
      function (error) {
        oj.Logger.error('Error in root start: ' + error.message);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Given that JET is an Oracle specific bundle of JS tools you're more likely to get an answer on the Oracle Technet forum dedicated to JET. [Find it here](https://community.oracle.com/community/development_tools/oracle-jet)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to move your router `go()` commands out of the main.js and into a viewModel that backs the login page and only runs if and when the user passes your authentication test by entering the right username/password.

If login is the default page you want them to see, change the router.configure and navData setup in `appController.js` to make that the default page:

```
self.router.configure({
     'login': {label: 'Login', isDefault: true},
      ...
```

Have a look at the [FixItFast sample code](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/globalExamples-App-FixItFast.html) for an example of a login page and the structure that supports it.  FixItFast is a much more involved example than the standard Starter templates because it assumes mobile-first, but the signin.html view and signin.js viewModel might give you good ideas.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. One of the challenge is to maintain the Single Page application. I am already on the dashboard page (Home Page), looks like I need to control the *visible* property of ojcomponents of navigation based on the login authentication.

Answer (score 1):

First you make your login page as default page.
Then (in your login.html) on button click you can call a function (function  in login.js) where validation of your username and password takes .

```
self.signIn = function() 
{
      //your validation

      if (login==success)
        {
           oj.Router.rootInstance.go('dashboard'); 
        }
     else
        {
            alert("check your details");
        }
};
```

Make sure that you have add your dashboard page in router config

```
 self.router.configure({
      'dashboard': {label: 'Dashboard'},
      'login': {label: '',isDefault: true}
                       });
```